# Pandas - Reading empty set from CSV using literal_eval

Tags: pandas, dataframe, abstract-syntax-tree

I have saved a Pandas data frame to a CSV file and in the process data type information was lost and set and lists were converted to strings.

Here is my csv file.

```
|id|words|tags
0|A|{'-', 'Drawings', 'Jude'}|[]
1|B|{'mafalda'}|[]
2|C|set()|[]
3|D|{'Sidestepping', 'flood'}|['mountain']
4|E|{'visvim','jack'}|[]
5|F|set()|[]
6|-G|<class 'object'>|<class 'object'>
```

I am able to read this csv file **if I remove index numbers 2,5, and 6** which contains empty sets represented as set() and null objects. I am using the following code for this.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv', sep='|' )
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(literal_eval)
df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(literal_eval)
```

However when there are empty sets, I am getting exception mentioning

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f44250fc250>
```

How can I read the empty sets correctly?

UPDATE :  jezrael has provided an answer to handle the empty sets. How can I handle the null objects also.

Also why Pandas is saving a empty set as 'set()' when it is saving a null list as [] and not 'list[]'

Update: A sample code which created the CSV with null objects.

```
col_names =  ['A', 'B']
df  = pd.DataFrame(columns = col_names)
df.loc[len(df)] = [2, 4]
df

df['C']=object
print(df)
print(type(df))
df.to_csv('Sample_File', sep='|', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please note that the answer is out of date. As from Python 3.9. onward `ast` will be able to parse 'set()' as an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) before converting to sets:

```
df['words'] = df['words'].replace('set()','{}').apply(literal_eval)
df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(literal_eval)

print (df)
  id                  words        tags
0  A    {Jude, -, Drawings}          []
1  B              {mafalda}          []
2  C                     {}          []
3  D  {Sidestepping, flood}  [mountain]
4  E         {jack, visvim}          []
5  F                     {}          []
```

EDIT:

```
def repl(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(x.replace('set()','{}'))
    except:
        return np.nan

df['words'] = df['words'].apply(repl)
df['tags'] = df['tags'].apply(repl)

print (df)
   id                  words        tags
0   A    {Jude, -, Drawings}          []
1   B              {mafalda}          []
2   C                     {}          []
3   D  {Sidestepping, flood}  [mountain]
4   E         {jack, visvim}          []
5   F                     {}          []
6  -G                    NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I have updated the handling of null objects also in the question.

Comment: @Erdnase - How should be replaced `<class 'object'>`  ? there is some class constructor?

Comment: In the original data frame before saving , these were NULL . We defined a column of object. Then only few of the rows were assigned values before saving. So we just want to read it as NULL objects.

Comment: @Erdnase - Cab yo ucheck EDIT? `NULL` means `np.nan` ?

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful method.  unassigned object was referred by me as null. I have added a snippet which creates such kind of text file for reference.